# Making anchor/connection points for lines on bitmaps in picturebox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am making a logical gates application and I can currently drag out bitmaps into the picturebox. These bitmaps are the logical gates. Now I need a way to draw the lines to connect inputs with gates. I would like to have the line sort of stick to connection or anchor points on the bitmap that I place but I have no idea how to do this.

Each bitmap dragged out is an object with a size and an x y position.

Thanks for any help! I have been searching for a solution for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically ended up making 10x10 rectangles positioned according to the height/width of the object that would update when the bitmap was moved. The bitmap was also its own rectangle.

Comment: Hi @UberBrainChild, when you've got an answer to your question you should indicate that it's the answer by clicking the tick next to it.  It doesn't matter that you answered it yourself, you should still tick it :)